# Scala Play Sample App Json Serializer errors

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I am trying Scala with Play framework and coming from 10+ years of Java/Spring experience

Below is the source code I am trying

Routes file

```
GET    /stock                      controllers.HomeController.saveStock
```

Sample Model object

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Stock(symbol: String = "", price: Double = 0d)

object Stock  {
  implicit def stockReads = Json.reads[Stock]
  implicit def stockWrites = Json.writes[Stock]
  implicit def stockFormat = Json.format[Stock]
}
```

Sample Controller

```scala
import models.Stock
import javax.inject._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc: ControllerComponents) {
  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
    def saveStock = Action{ implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    var stocks = List(Stock())
    println(stocks)
    Ok(Json.toJson(Stock)).as("application/json")
    //Ok
  }
}
```

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-server" % "2.8.8"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "5.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.19.7"
libraryDependencies += "ai.x" %% "play-json-extensions" % "0.42.0"
```

**Error - http://localhost:9000/**
No Json serializer found for type models.Stock.type. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

Comment: Have you tried to do what's suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the error message "*No Json serializer found for type `models.Stock.type`"*, one important thing to notice is the `.type` suffix.

It's referring to the `object Stock`, not the `case class`. That is the error is saying "*I don't know how to serialize `object Stock`*".

This is because you wrote `Json.toJson(Stock)` instead of `Json.toJson(Stock())` or maybe you meant `Json.toJson(stocks)`.

`Stock` refers to the `object` while `Stock()` is Instantiating the `case class`.

---

Also:

- you don't need to specify the `as(...)` if using a `JsObject` in the result.
- you dont'e need a `Reads` nor a `Writes` if you provide a `Format` (the later is providing the 2 former)
- use `val` rather than `var` (immutability is the strength of Scala)